# How to return a custom List with few fields from a custom query with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing a REST web service with Spring Boot 2 and Java 8. I have a problem in creating a list with few fields compared to when I get a list with all the fields of a table.

```java
@Query("SELECT c.idCliente, c.nome, c.cognome, c.username, c.email FROM Cliente c WHERE c.username LIKE %:username%")
List<Cliente> findClienteByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

The result is:

```
[
   3,
   null,
   null,
   "user",
   "aaa"
]
```

But when show all fields get this:

```
{"idCliente":3,"username":"user","nome":null,"cognome":null,"dataNascita":null,"email":"aaa","password":"ciao","dataCreazione":"2018-11-23T21:33:31.000+0000","instagram":null,"facebook":null,"google":null,"twitter":null,"attivo":"1","ultimaSospensione":null}
```

Why can't I get the field names along with the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you have to select a few fields you have to go with Spring Projection through DTO class. You have to define the constructor with the selected fields.

```
@Query("SELECT new Cliente(c.idCliente, c.nome, c.cognome, c.username, c.email) FROM Cliente c WHERE c.username LIKE %:username%")
List<Cliente> findClienteByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

You can refer below link with detailed information.
https://smarterco.de/spring-data-jpa-query-result-to-dto/

Or you can do the manual translation for each row using a mapper function.

```
 @Query("SELECT c.id, c.nome, c.cognome, c.username, c.email FROM Cliente c WHERE c.username LIKE %:username%")
List<Object[]> findClientDeatailsByuserName(@Param("username")String username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: Create the below mentioned constructor into an Cliente entity class.

```
Cliente(int idCliente,String noame,String cognome,String username,String email){
   this.idCliente=idCliente;
   this.nome=nome;
   this.cognome=cognome;
   this.username=username;
   this.email=email;   
 }
```

Call the query as:

```
@Query("SELECT new packageName.Cliente(c.idCliente, c.nome, c.cognome, c.username, c.email) FROM Cliente c WHERE c.username LIKE %:username%")
List<Cliente> findClienteByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
```

It will show all fields with value.